# How do you exclude a specific character pattern with regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I working with some regular expression matching and I'm trying to figure out how you would exclude a specific character pattern.  Specifically, I want to exclude the following pattern:

```
5 -       #in words: digit, space, dash & space)
```

I know how to exclude the components individually:  `[^5 ^-]` but I'm looking to exclude the specific pattern.   Is this possible?

Update - I'm using Ruby as my programming language.

Here is some sample input and desired output.:

```
Input:  1 - Blue-Stork Stables; 2 - Young, Robert, S.; 3 - Seahorse Stable; 4 - Carney, Elvis; 5 - Guerrero, Juan, Carlos-Martin; 6 - Dubb, Michael; 7 - Summers, Hope; 8 - DTH Stables; 9 - Peebles, Matthew\n
```

the desired output would be:

```
Output: Blue-Stork Stables; Young, Robert, S.; Seahorse Stable; Carney, Elvis; Guerrero, Juan, Carlos-Marting; Dubb, Michael; Summers, Hope; DTH Stables; Peebles, Matthew\n
```

Please take note of the dashes on Blue-Stork Stables and Juan Carlos-Martin.

Comment: What *exactly*  do you mean by "exclude"? Should only that exact pattern prevent a match, or if that pattern can be found at the start of the string, or anywhere in the string? Please provide some examples of strings you do/don't want to match.

Comment: There's no way `[^5 ^-]` works as you intend. The matches a *single character*, that is **not** `5`, ` `, `^` or  `-`.

Comment: I mean it will match everything except what I exclude. For example I would use this exclude [^\t]+  on a tab delimited file because it would match all the data and exclude the tabs.

Comment: Provide some sample input and output so that we know what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** So you mean "remove", not "exclude". No problem:

```
result = subject.gsub(/\d+ - /, '')
```

transforms your input into the desired output. I've taken the liberty to allow more than one digit (after all, if numbers reach 10 or higher, you probably want to remove those entirely, too. Right?).

---

(Old answer for "historical reasons")

Depending on what you mean by "exclude", it appears that you're looking for negative lookahead assertions:

```
^(?!.*\d - )
```

will fail on strings that contain `5 -` anywhere and succeed on all other strings:

```
"5 - "       // fail
"5 -"        // match
"abc5 - xyz" // fail
"foobar5 - " // fail
```

Comment: I would go with `^(?!\d+\s*-\s*).*`, but a lot of info is missing here to be sure...